# Unsatisfied Dependency Exception(Elasticsearch)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I want to elastic  search with spring boot, I get the following error

pox.xml:>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spring-elastiksearch</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application:>

```
package com.examples;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

kisi:>

```
package com.examples.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

import java.util.Date;

@Document(indexName = "kisiler")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Kisi {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(name = "ad", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String ad;

    @Field(name = "soyad", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String soyad;

    @Field(name = "adres", type = FieldType.Text)
    private String adres;

    @Field(name = "dogum_tarihi", type = FieldType.Date)
    private Date dogumTarihi;
}
```

kisiRepository:>

```
package com.examples.repository;

import com.examples.entity.Kisi;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface KisiRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Kisi, String> {


    @Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match\": {\"ad\": \"?0\"}}]}}")
    List<Kisi> getByCustomQuery(String search);

    List<Kisi>  findByAdLikeOrSoyadLike(String ad, String soyad);
}
```

kisiController:>

```
package com.examples.controller;

import com.examples.entity.Kisi;
import com.examples.repository.KisiRepository;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kisi")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KisiController {
    private final KisiRepository kisiRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Kisi kisi =new Kisi();
        kisi.setAd("Haydi");
        kisi.setSoyad("Kodlayalim");
        kisi.setAdres("test");
        kisi.setDogumTarihi(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        kisi.setId("K0001");
        kisiRepository.save(kisi);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{search}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Kisi>> getKisi(@PathVariable String search) {
        List<Kisi> kisiler = kisiRepository.findByAdLikeOrSoyadLike(search, search);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(kisiler);
    }
}
```

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-26T19:18:47.072+03:00 ERROR 17012 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kisiController' defined in file [C:\spring-examples\spring-elastiksearch\target\classes\com\examples\controller\KisiController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'kisiRepository' defined in com.examples.repository.KisiRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on Application: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at com.examples.Application.main(Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kisiRepository' defined in com.examples.repository.KisiRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on Application: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:536) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:79) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/kisiler], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:63) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.doCreate(IndicesTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.createWithMapping(IndicesTemplate.java:135) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:84) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/kisiler], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/kisiler], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:347) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.7.1.jar:8.7.1]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:313) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.7.1.jar:8.7.1]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.7.1.jar:8.7.1]
at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:153) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.7.1.jar:na]
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.ElasticsearchIndicesClient.create(ElasticsearchIndicesClient.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.7.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.lambda$doCreate$0(IndicesTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:71) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
... 52 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Try to put your exception in code format, easier to read. Also, what is the version of your ES server?